# Writing to a file py

Tags: python

if anyone can help me I need my code to display as such:

```
Hammad | Won | 5
```

The code I'm using is:

```
f = open("Statistics.txt", "a")

f.write(str(player_name) +''+ str(Outcome)+''+str(max_guesses)+"\n"

f = open("Statistics.txt", "r")

print(f.read())

f.close()
```

I need the output to be:

```
Hammad | Won | 6
```

Instead I'm getting:

```
Hammad Won 6
```

Comment: Have you tried writing the file in the format you need?
`f.write(str(player_name) +'|'+ str(Outcome)+'|'+str(max_guesses)+"\n"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python does not add `|` character automatically while string concatenation, you have to do it manually,

```
f.write(str(player_name) +' | '+ str(Outcome)+' | '+str(max_guesses)+"\n")
```

PS : `f.write` need a closing parenthesis(all functions do)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the write line with:

`f.write(f'{player_name} | {Outcome} | {max_guesses}\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Replace f.write with this

```
f.write(str(player_name)+'|'+str(Outcome)+'|'+str(max_guesses)+"\n"
```